# Evaluate performance of Self-organizing map for classification

Tags: matlab, neural-network, classification, cluster-analysis, self-organizing-maps

I'm trying to use a Self-Organizing map (SOM) as a clustering method on the Iris dataset.

```
% Load dataset
load iris.dat
X = iris(:,1:end-1);
true_labels = iris(:,end);

% Train SOM
net = newsom(X',[10,10],'hextop','linkdist');
net.trainParam.epochs = 100;
net = train(net,X');

% Assign examples to clusters
outputs = sim(net,X');
[~,assignment]  =  max(outputs);
```

How can I evaluate the performance of this SOM? I tried to compute the Adjusted Rand Index (ARI) between the true_labels and the assignments, but I don't know if this makes any sense. The ARI seems to converge to 0 for a large grid.

Answer (score 1):

SOM is not really a clustering algorithm, it is a representation learning method. Once you trained your SOM you can now project your data onto closest neurons and use their positions as new representation, where you run your favourite clustering algorithm. The only way in which SOM "is a clustering method" is if you run it with grid size equal to number of clusters. So for Iris, where you have 3 classes you would need a network that is just 3 nodes. Probably in a shape of a triangle graph wise.

Comment: You are not doing anyone a favor by answering off-topic questions, you should redirect these to the AI or Stats Stackexchange. And please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262573/why-shouldnt-i-answer-off-topic-questions-faq

Comment: How is this question off-topic? This is a litterally an assignment for a machine learning class.

Comment: @CodeGuy The question is "How can I evaluate the performance of this SOM?", you are asking if some metric makes sense, selecting metrics for ML problems is not a programming problem, there is the AI or Stats SE where these questions are on-topic, you do not need any programming to select a metric, and more importantly, pure machine learning problems like this are not programming problems, its irrelevant if this comes from a ML class or not.